# How to replace handles?

Tags: handlebars, replacement, grip-shifter

I've got an old bike from my friends, which basically looks good (just needs some oiling), but its handles are really beaten up and greesy. I couldn't find any screws or anything which keeps these handles in place - please see photo.

[image: LeftHandle]

Is it possible to replace handles without replacing the whole gear switching mechanism?

Comment: Note that the outer part of the assembly is missing.  There should be a non-twisting rubber piece running out to the end of the bar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The rubber degrades and goes super tacky and gross as you note. The rubber and plastic part does remove by pulling outwards - and could therefore be replaced - this is how you change cables on these SRAM gripshift. The problem however is that the rubber rotating part is probably not available as a spare part. The shifter unit itself is generally considered cheap enough as a whole.

Searching online for 'SRAM rotating grip assembly' does bring up some spare parts, though I can't see a straight match and they are about the same cost as a whole replacement unit. These seem to be for higher tier units.

A visit to your local SRAM Dealer might be helpful, they could look up the current spare parts catalogue with you and see if it's even listed as a spare, more categorically.

Bear in mind that replacement units come with their own inner cable, so it might be a reasonable time to go with new units and saving the cost of the inner cable as a nice part to freshen up too.

Answer (score 5):

I've "fixed" these in the past by putting some large heatshrink tube on, and warming it with a hot air gun.

This provides a new layer of hard rubber that encapsulates the old tacky stuff and looks acceptable.

You can also add several layers just out-board of the grip shift, to bring the level up even with the outside of the shifter